# Execution Failed for Task ':qr_code_scanner:parseDebugLocalResources' When Running on Different Machine

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm currently working on a Flutter project that utilizes the ***qr_code_scanner*** package. The application runs perfectly fine on my primary machine, but when I try to run the same codebase on a different machine, I'm encountering the following error:

> **Execution failed for task ':qr_code_scanner:parseDebugLocalResources'.**

Here's what I've tried so far to address the issue:

1. Cleaned the Project: Ran `flutter clean`, followed by `flutter pub get`
   and `flutter run`.
2. Ensured SDK Consistency: Made sure both machines have the same
   Flutter and Dart SDK versions.
3. Checked AndroidX Compatibility: Verified that the project is
   AndroidX compatible.
4. Updated the `qr_code_scanner` Package: Ensured I'm using the latest
   version.
5. Verified Resource Integrity: Ensured all required resources are
   correctly placed and accessible.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I'm wondering if anyone else has faced a similar issue and might have insights or suggestions on how to resolve it. I'd appreciate any guidance the community can provide.